# Only 1/4 linked Icons in container visible. [FireFox only, online only]

Tags: html, css

Hey guys here is my problem, my code looks like this offline(local):

[image: :D]

And like this online(mywebsite), as you can see it is missing the other links.

[image: :(]

It is a menu that floats along the page as you scroll, on the right.

Happens to me when using FireFox, latest version, in both Linux and Windows. All other browser seem fine both online and offline

I cant figure out what I've done wrong here.

Here is my **css:**

```
#sBRight{
    vertical-align: top;
    position: fixed;
    margin:0 0 0 90%;
    background: #161616;
    border: solid #b6b6b6 8px ;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

#socialButton{
    width:60px;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    display: block;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="sBRight">
<a href="http://facebook.com/"><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="FaceBook" id="socialButton"></a>

<a href="http://za.linkedin.com/"><img src="images/linkedin.png" alt="LinkedIn" id="socialButton"></a>

<a href="https://plus.google.com/"><img src="images/googleplus.png" alt="Google Plus" id="socialButton"></a>

<a href="mailto:never@never.fal"><img src="images/email.png" alt="Email Me" id="socialButton"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks fine for me.. http://jsfiddle.net/qR4J3/

Comment: I thought it might be cached, but I booted into my other OS, along with clearing my cache and using ctrl + f5.

Comment: And what were your results? Is it working now?

Comment: Nope, still not. Offline it works in all browsers. But as soon as I upload it it breaks in firefox.

Comment: can u provide online link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by renaming the 3 images,

`facebook.png` to `fb.png`

`googleplus.png` to `gp.png`

`linkedin.png` to `li.png`

And then changed their names in the `html` too.
This is strange because I triple checked the filenames. I also `div`'d up the icons and changed their `css`.

### **HTML:**

```
<div id="sBRight">

    <div class="socialButton">
        <a target="_blank" href="http://facebook.com"><img src="images/fb.png" alt="FaceBook"/></a>
    </div>

    <div class="socialButton">
    <a target="_blank" href="http://za.linkedin.com/"><img src="images/li.png" alt="LinkedIn"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="socialButton">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://plus.google.com"><img src="images/gp.png" alt="Google Plus"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="socialButton">
        <a href="mailto:never@never.fal><img src="images/email.png" alt="Email Me"></a>
    </div>

</div>
```

### **CSS:**

```
#sBRight{
    position: fixed;
    margin: 20% 5% 0 90%;
    background: #161616;
    border: solid #b6b6b6 10px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width:80px;
}

.socialButton{
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    display: block;
}

#sBRight img{
    width: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Renaming the images solved your problem, which was caused by AdBlock not showing social networking images. Ensure that AdBlock is turned off when you're testing for image loading.

> You can use Adblock Plus to remove all social media buttons from every website, making sure that social networks can’t create a profile about you based on the websites you visit.

See https://adblockplus.org/en/features for more info.

Answer (score 1):

First, you are feeding multiple instances of an ID to the page, that's a no-no. ID's are for objects that would be named and appear only once whereas classes are for items that would repeat on a page.

Otherwise, I'm not seeing anything that would cause this. You may have some additional css that is overriding it though. Can you link the site it's on or link the actual html and css?

Comment: FF26, Chrome, IE all working as intended. I am willing to bet there is a css statement somewhere that is causing the issue. Also, I changed socialButton to a class.

If you really want to just avoid this issue, wrap them with spans and adjust the span or, heaven's forbid, use a 4 row table (*ducks and runs away*)

Comment: Still doesnt work after I went through the CSS. Fixed the id's and classes

Comment: Spans dont help either. If I disable images in FF I can see the `alt` text as a link though. Progress.

Comment: @VikingBlooded - I've been known to do that too, if our designer/css expert is busy on other projects. And you know what? No one died!